# Undefined values being passed to MySQL database through React and Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

My front-end in React keeps passing through undefined values to the back-end server in Node. I am trying to create a registration container that will create an account in the database.

Here is my on click function:

```
register(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let newUser = {
          name : this.state.name,
          password : this.state.password,
          email : this.state.email
        }
        Axios.post('http://localhost:2999/Join', newUser).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);

            if (response.data.success) {
                console.log("Successful Register");
                this.props.close();
            } else {
                console.log("Failed to Register");
                console.log(response.data.error);
            }
        });
    }
```

I currently have it setup where the state of each box in the form is updated through the onChange function:

```
handleNameChange(event) {
        this.setState({name : event.target.value});
    }

    handlePwChange(event) {
      this.setState({password : event.target.value});
    }

    handleEmailChange(event) {
      this.setState({email : event.target.value});
    }
```

Here is the POST function in my Server.js:

```
app.post('/Join', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.params.name;
    console.log(name);
    const password = req.params.password;
    console.log(password);
    const email = req.params.email;
    console.log(email);
    const REGISTER_USER_QUERY = `INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES ('${name}', '${password}', '${email}');`;
    connection.query(REGISTER_USER_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            return res.send('Successfully registered player');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the data from `req.body`.
So in your code just need change:

```
app.post('/Join', (req, res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    console.log(name);
    const password = req.body.password;
    console.log(password);
    const email = req.body.email;
    console.log(email);
    const REGISTER_USER_QUERY = `INSERT INTO users (name, password, email) VALUES ('${name}', '${password}', '${email}');`;
        connection.query(REGISTER_USER_QUERY, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
           return res.send(err);
        } else {
           return res.send('Successfully registered player');
      }
  });
});
```

You should use `req.params` when passing parameters from url.
Suppose you would like to get data from user whose id is 1000.

Your route would be:

```
app.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    res.json({userid: id})
})
```

In the example above, if you make a request in route http://localhost:3000/user/1000

We have the response:

```
{userid: 1000}
```

Comment: That did it right there! It was because I was using params instead of body. Thank you! Your advice on params will help me when I start working on the login side of things.

Answer (score 0):

how are u calling each "handleChange" in the inputs?

you should be doing this:

```
handleNameChange = event => this.setState({name: event.target.value})

<input value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
```

Check two things: that you are calling fine the onChange from the input, and that you are using an arrow function in handleNameChange OR you are doing a bind to the handleNameChange in the constructor of your class component.

Comment: I did do a bind in the constructor to each handleChange. Before I did that I would get a setState could not pass an undefined value error. I noticed that I did not have the value={this.state.name}, which I did add but I'm still getting undefined values being passed.